# database migration not null causing issue with DBeaver?

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I am trying to do a simple database migration so I can copy my current online database locally.

I am using Dbeaver for the migration and a few tables are giving me an error. It might be due to the server mysql version not corresponding with the local mysql version. Here is the error:

```
Error starting data transfer
  Can't create target table:
CREATE TABLE databasedev.discount_coupons(
    coupons_id varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    coupons_description varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    coupons_discount_amount decimal(15,12) NOT NULL,
    coupons_discount_type enum(8) NOT NULL,
    coupons_date_start datetime,
    coupons_date_end datetime,
    coupons_max_use int NOT NULL,
    coupons_min_order decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
    coupons_min_order_type enum(8),
    coupons_number_available int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (coupons_id)
)
  Can't create target table:
CREATE TABLE databasedev.discount_coupons(
    coupons_id varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    coupons_description varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    coupons_discount_amount decimal(15,12) NOT NULL,
    coupons_discount_type enum(8) NOT NULL,
    coupons_date_start datetime,
    coupons_date_end datetime,
    coupons_max_use int NOT NULL,
    coupons_min_order decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
    coupons_min_order_type enum(8),
    coupons_number_available int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (coupons_id)
)
    SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8) NOT NULL,
    coupons_date_start datetime,
    coupons_date_end datetime,
    coupons_' at line 5
    SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8) NOT NULL,
    coupons_date_start datetime,
    coupons_date_end datetime,
    coupons_' at line 5
      You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8) NOT NULL,
    coupons_date_start datetime,
    coupons_date_end datetime,
    coupons_' at line 5
      You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8) NOT NULL,
    coupons_date_start datetime,
    coupons_date_end datetime,
    coupons_' at line 5
```